# Incrementing a field in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I've never had or attempted to do this before, but what I want to do is instead of getting the value out of the database and adding 1 to it just to do an update query is just do one UPDATE query and incrementing the field...

Is there a way of using a JOIN query to get the current value and then updating it again with the new one?

As it's literally just incrementing an INT number I thought there may be way around it.

Answer (score 7):

```
update table_name set field_name=field_name + 1 where <condition>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do the following:

```
UPDATE table_name set field_to_increment = field_to_increment + 1 WHERE <cond>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```sql
UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = yourcolumn+1 WHERE yourid=123;
```

Comment: Cheers. Bit of a blonde moment from me.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to increment a value in a cell:

```
UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 WHERE id = 123;
```